I have a software that will only accept input from a specific game controller and i want that to change
So I work for a company and we have just recently purchased an ROV. The controller the ROV company gave us upon purchase isnt fit for use and i want to use a different one, preferably a flight stick. However, the software that controls the ROV and inputs/outputs is software locked to only recognise this specific controller and i cant find a way to change it.
Ive tried so far using VJoy, changing details in Regedit to attempt to make the controllers unrecognisable from eachother but ive not managed to do it as of yet and i dont really know enough about HID devices. So i was wondering if there was a way for one controller to directly mimic another controler 1:1 so that the software wouldnt be able to tell the difference.
